# Error on create an NPM project and NPM Install, error errno 4294967295

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

I can't run NPM Install on this computer, other laptop it works good.
What if tried reinstall Windows, Visual Code, WSL 2, NodeJS, NVM.. without success.

I have tried just: `npx create-react-app hello_world` nothing works. Search on Google of course but also no solution that works.

I have removed folder `node_modules` and done `npm cache clean --force`

NPM Version: 6.14.13

Last part of error log:

```
46182 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
46183 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts" "cra-template"
46184 verbose node v14.17.0
46185 verbose npm  v6.14.13
46186 error code ELIFECYCLE
46187 error errno 4294967295
46188 error core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
46188 error Exit status 4294967295
46189 error Failed at the core-js@2.6.12 postinstall script.
46189 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
46190 verbose exit [ 4294967295, true ]
```

Hope some of you have another solution which I can try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error log you provide indicates that there is a problem with the `postinstall` script on `core-js@2.6.12`. That is a legacy version of `core-js` but that's what `create-react-app` currently uses.

The [`postinstall` script for that version of `core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/ffb783b746849c2b14258e6bef6106f1dcab2a66/postinstall.js) prints a banner asking for funding for the project. That is the only thing it does.

[Line 34](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/ffb783b746849c2b14258e6bef6106f1dcab2a66/postinstall.js#L34) of the code shows a bunch of environment variables that will bypass the banner printing if they are set. These environment variables are:

- `ADBLOCK`
- `CI`
- `DISABLE_OPENCOLLECTIVE`
- `SILENT`
- `OPEN_SOURCE_CONTRIBUTOR`

If you set one of those environment variables, the error will (probably) not occur. (I say "probably" because I don't have a machine that is having the problem you are having, and so I can't test.)

Answer (score 2):

It might be hard to solve your problem, cause of lack of information, but there are some steps, that you can follow.

First of all try this (you should replace path with your shell path):

`npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

`NodeJs` spawning separate process for `core-js` (you have proof in your logs `node -e ...`), to do that it needs shell to run it. Sometimes on `Windows` instead of taking shell path from environment variable it might be hardcoded, so if your shell isn't on hardcoded path, it will fail. That's might be a reason why your command failing with `core-js`.

If it doesn't help, you can try those steps:

1. Try to install different versions of `node` (you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)),
2. Make sure your `firewall` is not blocking your application (you can try to turn it off for a moment),
3. Try to run your terminal/IDE as admin (`right click` -> `run as administrator`) - **be careful with that (read comment below)**,
4. Try to checkout other `react` or `pure js` application from github (e.g. [react-bootstrap-starter](https://github.com/ChrisAchinga/react-bootstrap-starter) or [minimal-react-starter](https://github.com/ahfarmer/minimal-react-starter)),
5. Try to use `powershell` / `cmd` / `git bash` and just check if simple `npm install` with minimal js project will run.
6. If nothing of above doesn't work run your command with `--loglevel verbose` to get more information about error.

If nothing of above worked for you, please update your post with extended logs and try to provide more information what you have done after reinstalling windows, what model of laptop are you using and what exact windows (version and type e.g. `Windows 10 N Professional, build 8019`).

Comment: please do not run unverified 3rd party software as administrator (npm, package.json can execute anything)

Comment: @kaznovac That's worth to notice. I've updated the post.

Comment: Your solution wasn't quite right for me, but you got me on the right path by pointing out "NodeJs (is) spawning (a) separate process for core-js". I added node to my PATH variable and npm install started working! Thanks!